# Pages do not load correctly only when click Refresh on Win7+IIS7.5

Tags: javascript, css, iis-7.5

I recently migrate my development website from old computer (WinXP with IIS5.1) to new computer (Win7 with IIS7.5). The application developped using ASP.NET with bunch of javascript and CSS files.

On the new computer, the virtual directory is created under Default Web Site with default configuration but enable ASP.NET Impersonate and Windows Authentication (Anonymous disable)

The application used the Classic Pipeline on Classic .NET AppPool (.NET 2.0) that comes with IIS7.5.

With above configuration, application run fine on IIS5.1 but not on IIS7.5. The page will load correctly but if refresh button is hit, page will load incorrectly by displaying only ASP.NET page without loading JS and CSS.

However, by retyping URL in the address bar and hit enter to reload page, it displays correctly.

At first, I thought it's because IE9 but I can use IE9 to open application on old computer without problem.

If anyone know any clues, please tell me.

Thank you

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, does the page load correctly after clicking refresh, right? Are you declaring the DOCTYPE?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Pages do not load correctly when refresh but load correctly if typing directly to the address bar. DOCTYPE does not declare.

Comment: IE is very fussy about it. Try declaring the DOCTYPE and see if it works. Just add this at the top of your pages <DOCTYPE html>

Comment: I have the same problem but it only seems to happen in chrome browser. page loads fine when I hit refresh all css disappears. When I look in the resources the type of the file changes to text/html from text/css