# page refresh causes css to be ignored

Tags: css, google-chrome, iis-6, mime-types

My page loads fine then as soon as you hit the refresh button all the styling disappears.

It seems to be specific to chrome. If I look at the network tab I see that my css files returned with 304 Not modified but the type has changed to text/html. On initial load it is text/css.

If I turn off caching everything works fine.

I saw a similar question on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912763/pages-do-not-load-correctly-only-when-click-refresh-on-win7iis7-5) but It was working before and I have not changed servers.

I seem to have narrowed it down to a problem with one css file.
In particular adding a background image.

```
body {background:#b4dfff url(/images/backgrounds/background.jpg) no-repeat fixed top;
text-align:left;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #585858;
font-size: 12px;    
}
```

if I remove the background the problem occurs significantly less frequently.
I tried changing it to

```
background-color:#b4dfff;
Background-image:url(/images/backgrounds/background.jpg) no-repeat fixed top;
```

that didn't work

Comment: Please post your html/css and if possible a link to your page or a jsfiddle example.

Comment: [www.kidobi.com](http://www.kidobi.com) is the live site. I am using asp.net. Another clue is it works fine on google chrome version 25. It is only on the new version 26 that it fails.

Comment: Another note it works fine locally when I debug

Comment: Try fixing some of the errors indicated when you run your site through these two validators: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ and http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same thing @Leo after the latest Chrome update. Thanks for the text/html clue. Will look further into it.

Comment: I can see you posted a the questions in the google product forum as well. In case anyone else comes across this question, they might find more info there: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/zID6uQQfKH8/TG43WUE9HqsJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this has to do with chrome handling the 304 response.

Chrome asks for content and receives a 304 response saying it is not modified.

When IIS returns a 304 response it has content-type in it. Chrome doesn't ignore the content type and looks and sees that the content type has been changed since IIS just returns the default type chrome thinks the file is no longer a stylesheet and doesn't load it.

So in order to fix this we made it reload stylesheets everytime.
I have not figured out an easy way to modify the 304 response so that it does not include content-type.

Here is the google issue
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246875

Answer (score 1):

same exact problem is mentioned here : http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/zID6uQQfKH8
It seems like a temporary solution could be

> turning off ETags and setting no-cache in HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

An easy work around I found was to add "!important" to the end of each line in your css file to ensure it overrides whatever the default css styling was.

I went over the items that kept reverting back to their original styling once the page was refreshed and now they maintain the styling provided in the css file.

An example:

```
.div {
    display: block !important;
    margin-top: 10px !important; 
}
```